# How to get the SelectedItem value from a ListBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I use a grid within my ListBox control to display images with their respective IDs.

The ID field is bound to grid column 1.  I want to use the ListBox's SelectionChanged event to select the ID value (i.e. grid column 1 value).  How can I do this?

Below is a code snippet of my XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source= ListToLoad}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ImgID}"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding ImageX}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast selected item to type of bounded data and then get Id from converted object.

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            ObservableCollection<Product> products=new ObservableCollection<Product> ();
            Product p=new Product { ProductId=1,Name="Suger" };
            products.Add (p);
            p=new Product { ProductId=2,Name="Bread" };
            products.Add (p);
            p=new Product { ProductId=3,Name="Rice" };
            products.Add (p);

            lstProducts.ItemsSource=products;
        }

        private void lstProducts_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Product p=(Product)lstProducts.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show (p.ProductId.ToString ());
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of what you are asking, you need to use 'SelectedItem' property of Listbox to bind it's selected item to a property in your code behind/View Model. The SelectedItem property in viewmodel will have the required ID property that you need. This approach will be better compared to using selection changed event.

For example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox2" **SelectedItem ={Binding SelectedImage}**  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source= ListToLoad}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

You will have to have a SelectedImage property in your ViewModel/Class code:

```
private <Image/type of property> _selectedImage;

public <Image/type of property> SelectedImage
{
get { return _selectedImage;}
set
_selectedImage = value;

if(value != null)
{
  <imageId> = value.ImageId;
}

}
```

Then when you will be selecting an item in Listbox, SelectedImage's setter will be fired and you will get selected image. And then you can get ImageId from SelectedImage in the setter method.

Comment: Rohit, would it be possible for you to provide a sample of your solution?

Comment: You should always give a try first. There are numerous similar posts on stackoverflow. But i have edited my answer. You can refer it.